# How to make the checkbox selected when click the label?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<input type="checkbox"  />  
<label>I agree</label>
```

Now when I click "I agree", nothing happens, I'd like to make the checkbox `checked`, what's the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`for` and `id` attributes

```
<input id="thisinput" type="checkbox"  />  
<label for="thisinput">I agree</label>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PNYNR/

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative to what @stevether suggested, you can also wrap the label around the checkbox

```
<label><input type="checkbox"  /> I agree</label>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WDerc/